# Call to undefined relationship [title] on model [App\Models\Employee]

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

working with Laravel 9 and in My App there are Relationship one to many with Employee Model between both Title and Salary.
Employee Model

```
public function titles(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Title::class, 'emp_id');
    }

    public function salaries(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Salary::class, 'emp_id');
    }
```

Salary Model

```
 public function employee(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'emp_no');
    }
```

Title Model

```
public function employee(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'emp_no');
    }
```

now I am going to get all data using EmployeeController getEmployee function as well EmployeeController.php

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Employee;
use App\Models\Title;
use App\Models\Salary;


class EmployeeController extends Controller
{
    public function getEmployee() {
        return response()->json(Employee::with('title','salary')->get(), 200);
      
    }
}
```

and My api.php call is like this

```
Route::get('employees','App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController@getEmployee');
```

but result shown following error message as well
`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException: Call to undefined relationship [title] on model [App\Models\Employee]. in file`  
then how could I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, you have to update your getEmployee function in the EmployeeController to specify the correct relationship. Based on your code, the relationships are named "titles" and "salaries". Here's the correct code:

```php
public function getEmployee() {
    return response()->json(Employee::with('titles', 'salaries')->get(), 200);
}
```

Comment: got following error `Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'titles.emp_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: sel`

Comment: @amaruwakoi I bet it is emp_no instead of emp_id as in your other relations...

Comment: @Henning yes you are 100% correct